# How to read the newly appended lines of a growing log file continuously in julia?

Tags: file-io, julia

There is shell command:

```
tail -n0 -f /path/to/growing/log
```

to display the newly appended lines of a file continuously.

Please guide me in achieving the objective in Julia!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just repeatedly read the file:

```
file = open("/path/to/growing/log")
seekend(file) # ignore contents that are already there to match the `-n0` option

while true
    sleep(0.2)
    data = read(file, String)
    !isempty(data) && print(data)
end
```

Comment: This is a nice answer. It is just worth to mention that it has two limitations (which in most cases should not be problematic): 1) it assumes that your file is only appended to (not rewritten) and 2) it does not buffer the output till the end of line character is written to a file.